# How to identify if a given Hasse diagram is a lattice

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations, lattice-orders

How to identify if a given Hasse diagram is a lattice?
[image: Hasse diagram]

Comment: The first step is knowing what a lattice is. Do you know what a lattice is? Then: do you know what a Hasse diagram is depicting with its lines and points?

Answer (score 3):

For a partial order to be a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)), it needs a join (a minimal upper bound) for any two of its elements. In your diagram, $2,3$ don't have an upper bound at all -- hence this is not a lattice.